# List a specific file in Powershell and assign it to variable

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to fetch a file with extension **.sln** file. And assign it to a variable so that I can use it it later as a variable.

```
PS C:\My_Agent\_work\1\s> Get-Item *.sln


Directory: C:\My_Agent\_work\1\s


   Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
   ----                -------------         ------ ----
   -a----       15-06-2021     17:17           1739 project.sln
```

From this output I only want to fetch **project.sln** file and assign it to a variable in Powershell. How to achieve this.

Comment: By using the assignment operator `=`: `$item = Get-Item *.sln`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for the response but its not useful. I am looking for a solution where only .sln file will be assigned to a variable.

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't find my suggestion useful, but I fail to see what's wrong with it? If you're concerned the pattern `*.sln` resolves multiple files, then you'll have to pick one, eg. the first one: `$item = Get-Item *.sln |Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I agree definetely there is no wrong in the solution and it works perfectly, but it gives me the solution with complete details of my **.sln** file. Like Mode, lastwritetime, length, Name parameteres. So I need only output as a **Project.sln** file and it needs to be assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$files = (Get-Item *.sln).name
$files
```